Using Jotai with Tanstack Query and KindeAuth JWT in atomWithQuery
I am trying to use the TanStack Query extension to Jotai. The direct integration to the state management is sweet, but the limitations with not being a top level function for react hooks seems problematic.
I have a simple atomWithQuery:
export const myDataAtom = atomWithQuery((get) => ({
  queryKey: ['getData', get(jwtToken)],
  queryFn: async ({queryKey: [,  jwtToken]}) => {
    const resp = await fetch(`datauri`, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${jwtToken}`
      },
      mode: "cors",
      method: "GET",
    });

    if (!resp.ok) {
      return Promise.reject(resp.statusText);
    }

    return await resp.json();
  }
}));

The problem here is I need to feed my JWT token to the aurthorization header. I am using Kinde Auth, which supplies a hook to always have an up to date token refreshed. I attempted wrapping that in its own atom and inject it to the query atom:
const jwtToken = atomWithQuery((get) => ({
  queryKey: ["jwtToken"],
  queryFn: async () => {

    //Not allowed because I'm using a hook inside atomWithQuery.
    const { getToken } = useKindeAuth();
    
    const t = await getToken();

    return t;
  }
}))

I considered creating a component which sets the atom, but that seems counter intuitive when that's really what you are trying to wrap with atomWithQuery.
The same could be said about the general structure of the atomWithQuery as it's also impossible to use some abstraction over fetch as a hook (in which I actually have implemented the await getToken() along with some error handling).
export const myDataAtom = atomWithQuery((get) => ({
  queryKey: ['getData'],
  queryFn: async () => {

     const { get } = useFetch();
     const data = await get<MyDatType>("myUrI");  

     return data; 

  }
}));

What is the best practice / correct way to do this?
